# MVC Refresh Partial View after Ajax HTTPPost

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am tryng to update a partial view after an Ajax HttpPost.

This is the controller for the Partial view:

```
    public PartialViewResult BrtMagazzino(DataMagazzino m)
    {
        if (Session["Data"] != null)
        {
            DateToView dt = (DateToView)Session["Data"];
            ViewBag.comm = dt.commSelected.COMMITTENTE;
            ViewBag.corriere = "Bartolini";
        }
        return PartialView(m);
    }
```

This is the code for the view that include the partial:

```
<div id="view-Bartolini">
   @{
      Html.RenderAction("BartoliniMagazzino", "Partial", new { m = item });
    }
</div>
```

This is the code for the button:

```
<input class='btn btn-info btnBordero' type='button' value='Salva Borderò' data-corriere="@ViewBag.corriere" data-magazzino="@Model.NomeMagazzino" data-committente="@ViewBag.comm" />
```

This is the code for the click of this button:

```
$(function () {
    $('.btnBordero').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        _self = $(this);
        var uf = new FormData();
        uf.append('corriere', _self.data('corriere'));
        uf.append('magazzino', _self.data('magazzino'));
        uf.append('committente', _self.data('committente'));
        var url = "/Partial/SaveBordero";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: uf,
            error: function (ts) { alert(ts.responseText) 
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#view-Bartolini").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The SaveBordero function have this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveBordero(FormCollection form)
{
   DataMagazzino dt = new DataMagazzino();
   // Do something
   return PartialView("BartoliniMagazzino", new { m = dt });
}
```

All works fine but when i call the return PartialView in SaveBordero function the ajax call always go in the error part. I don't know how to go in success and update the partial view

Comment: In your Ajax call remove `dataType: 'json',`. This represents what you get from server and it's not json but html.

Comment: have you set a breakpoint in your server side code? seems like an error is being thrown on the backend

Comment: Remove the datatype property as  @derloopkat suggested. the jquery will guess the dataType using the response headers and take care of it.

Comment: I have try to put `dataType:'html'` or delete dataType but it doesn't change the result

Comment: I have put a breakpoint on the last return of the return and all works fine but when the ajax return it always go on the error state

Comment: That means you have some other issue which is causing the code to be thrown to error. What response you are getting from the network call ? Is it 200 OK ?

Comment: The text of the error is "object reference not set to an instance of an object" but i can't understand where

Comment: There are a some things missing and some things that should be omitted. For one, remove the contentType: false. Additionally, you may have an issue with the call being cached, making it difficult to get updated error results. So, add this line: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); above the "$.ajax({" line. As well as, cache: false, within the ajax call; you really should only need 1 or the other.
Also, make sure that your site is not setup as an application url: "http://localhost/mysite/controller/action". This will cause you to not hit the controller method you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this row: `return PartialView("BartoliniMagazzino", new { m = dt });`

If i call a new m Model this is an anonymus type and the system doesn't reconize it.

I have solved it just writing: `return PartialView("BartoliniMagazzino", dt);`

Thanks to all